# Error Message in view: "#&lt;Location::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8d79d3de30&gt;"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

New to Rails and trying to work with Google Maps API.  I am looking to loop through and show markers for each geolocated location in the database.  When I open the console in the window and look for for the variable [places], which should have the value of all of my `@locations`, I get the above error message.  Any help please?  Thank you.

map.html.erb:   (

```
 <h1>map Page</h1>
```

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.725685, -122.156830),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var places = '<%= @locations %>';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
    var places = '<%= @locations %>';
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(places[i].description);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Locations Controller:

```
def map
      @locations = Location.all
    end
```

Locations Model:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :location_name
      t.string :location_address
      t.string :location_description
      t.float :lat
      t.float :lng

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Route:

```
get '/locations/map', to: "locations#map", as: "map"
```

Comment: Just noticed,  and I removed the second 
    var places = '<%= @locations %>'; 

from inside the loop.  Same issue though.

Comment: Hello, please add full error information

Comment: "#&lt;Location::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8d7939e758&gt;"

Is the only error I get, and it only shows up int he console when I type "places".  No other errors.

Comment: `Location::ActiveRecordRelation` is  not an error it's a class that represents `ActiveRecord::Relation` and the thing you see in the console is most likely the result of `@locations.inspect`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I thought with the @locations = Location.all  would have taken care of making the variable available to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails don't know how to serialize your @locations variable, try something like(base on what you want):

```
var places = <%= @locations.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Comment: That did it, I can access my objects.  Thank you!